# Can't run old games with wine. init_opengl Failed to load libGL: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: wine, games, intel-graphics, 32-bit, opengl

I'm trying to run an old game (Colin Mcrae Rally 2.0) with wine and I get this error when running `wine game_executable.exe`:

```
0009:err:wgl:init_opengl Failed to load libGL: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
0009:err:wgl:init_opengl OpenGL support is disabled.    
wine: Unhandled page fault on read access to 00000000 at address 004A8BAD (thread 0009), starting debugger...
```

When I run `locate libGL.so.1` I get an output of:

```
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/128/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/128/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.0.0
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.0.0
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.0.0
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/60/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/60/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.7.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.7.0
```

My wine version: `wine-5.0 (Ubuntu 5.0-3ubuntu1)`

Ubuntu 20.04 `5.4.0-58-generic #64-Ubuntu x86_64`

I'm running an older PC with Intel I5-2400 with Intel HD 2000 graphics with no external graphics card. `00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)`

Comment: try playonliniux. On winehq I see only testet with older wine versions. https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=3165